# Why I am getting Multiple controller types were found that match the URL?

Tags: c#

I had one project callled Shopex.

And I renamed to HR

Now Requesting the controller

I get the following error

Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types:
HR.Web.Controllers.EmployeeController
Shopex.Web.Controllers.EmployeeController

I changed

```
public static void ConfigureMvc(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "HR.Web.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

so I added the name space HR.Web.Controllers

now do I need to do that in every controller class as an attribute

here is my controller

```
namespace HR.Web.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("admin/employees")]
    public class EmployeeController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
        private readonly int _pageSize;

     
        public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService EmployeeService)
            : base()
        {
            _employeeService = EmployeeService;
            _pageSize = 10;
        }

        
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int pageIndex = 1, string q = "")
        {
            var employees = await GetEmployees(pageIndex, q, true);
            return View(employees);
        }

        [Route("unique")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Unique(int pageIndex = 1, string q = "")
        {
            return Redirect("~/admin/Departments");

        }

        [Route("add")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("add")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Employee employee)
        {
            await _employeeService.AddAsync(employee);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }





        [Route("edit/{id:int:min(1)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var employee = await _employeeService.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);
        }


        [Route("edit/{id:int:min(1)}")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            await _employeeService.UpdateAsync(employee);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }





        [Route("delete/{id:int:min(1)}")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var isAuthorized = await _employeeService.Delete(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        private async Task<IList<Employee>> GetEmployees(int pageIndex, string keyword, bool shared)
        {
            if (pageIndex < 1)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
            }
            var list = await _employeeService.GetAllAsync(pageIndex, _pageSize, keyword, shared);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `[Route("edit/{id:int:min(1)}")]` twice, is it intended?

Comment: @Rafalon one for post and one for get

Comment: Yeah but your post is `Edit(Employee employee)`, it does not have `id` as parameter

Comment: I know it was working before when project name was shopex

Comment: There are routes that look like duplicates but have no verb attribute. I don't think they should be the cause, but it's easy to check by changing or removing them. If something is suspect and easy to test, I'd start with that. Also the error says multiple controller types, but you're only showing one controller. Are you sure there aren't other controllers with matching routes?

Answer (score 1):

As per the erroe,

```
The request has found the following matching controller types: HR.Web.Controllers.EmployeeController Shopex.Web.Controllers.EmployeeController
```

which means you have multiple `EmployeeController`. Check whether you have multiple controllers in `HR.Web.Controllers` and `Shopex.Web.Controllers`. If no then there might be duplicate controllers in your compiled dlls (check bin folder).